# Retrieve values from an array to store inside a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following array of data that is dumped on my site from Twitter.

```
array(4) {  
    ["oauth_token"]=> string(50) "19497918-McrcAAd1qrZwWaHljVPNbWVTSSrjolsybKwSXvtQ2" 
    ["oauth_token_secret"]=> string(39) "Mixl5gYZjxQqzGhs1q0GoP9DDBwxVDWfBRgldJE"    
    ["user_id"]=> string(8) "19497958" 
    ["screen_name"]=> string(6) "Liam" 
}
```

I want to somehow store this inside my table. My table structure is:

```
id   |   oauth_token   |   oauth_token_secret   |   user_id   |   screen_name
```

I am currently trying to insert my data with the following statement

```
$qry = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (access_token) VALUES (?)');
$qry->execute(array($access_token));
```

However, this throws a page error and my page will no longer load. How can I correct this?

Comment: What if someone gets malicious data in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your variable already is an array and is perfect for a [`prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) statement, do this:

```
$qry = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users 
              (oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, user_id, screen_name)
              VALUES (:oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret, :user_id, :screen_name)');
$qry->execute($access_token);
```

It's exactly like doing this, which is how we usually see prepared statements in `PDO`:

```
$qry = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users SET (oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, user_id, screen_name) VALUES (:oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret, :user_id, :screen_name)');
$qry->execute(array(
    'oauth_token' => "19497918-McrcAAd1qrZwWaHljVPNbWVTSSrjolsybKwSXvtQ2",
    'oauth_token_secret' => "Mixl5gYZjxQqzGhs1q0GoP9DDBwxVDWfBRgldJE",
    'user_id' => "19497958",
    'screen_name' => "Liam"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the name of your array is: $access_token and it has values(not empty).

```
$qry = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (access_token) 
 VALUES ($access_token["oauth_token"], $access_token["oauth_token_secret"],   
 $access_token["user_id"], $access_token["screen_name"])');

 $qry->execute($access_token);
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `user_id` should probably be an integer since it's only numbers.

Your code should probably look something like this to work the way you want it to.

```
$userarray = array(4) {  
    ["oauth_token"]=> string(50) "19497918-McrcAAd1qrZwWaHljVPNbWVTSSrjolsybKwSXvtQ2" 
    ["oauth_token_secret"]=> string(39) "Mixl5gYZjxQqzGhs1q0GoP9DDBwxVDWfBRgldJE"    
    ["user_id"]=> int(8) "19497958" 
    ["screen_name"]=> string(6) "Liam" 
}

$qry = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, user_id, screen_name) VALUES (:oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret, :user_id, :screen_name)');
$qry->execute($userarray);
```